# heeelp, i keep getting a read underline under foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

```
do
{
    //string test = questions[qCounter] = objReader.ReadLine();


    string test = question.Split('?')[qCounter];
    qCounter++;

    foreach (string part in test)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(part);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
} while (objReader.Peek() != -1 && qCounter < quest);
```

Comment: Do you mean a read squiggle line?  If so what message do you get when you hover the cursor over it.

Comment: Your variable `test` is a `string` you can only use foreach on a collection type such as `List<string>` or an array, or similar.  And as @taquion noted, if you change `string` to `char` it will work since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: part should be char

Comment: @ChrisDunaway String is an `IEnumerable<char>` so you should have no issue using a foreach on it.

Comment: `test` is a string, you cannot foreach over it and expect `string`s. Should be `foreach (char part in test)`

Comment: Not true @ChrisDunaway, string implements IEnumerable

Comment: @ChrisDunaway `string` is a collection of `char`, so the problem is the variable type will not work for casting.

Comment: @juharr - Yep, realized my mistake after clicking "Add Comment".

Comment: Change `foreach (string part in test)` to `foreach (char part in test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `foreach` on a `string` will produce a sequence of `char`, so declaring `part` as a `string` is not valid. Declare `part` as `char` or use `var`.

```
do
{
    //string test = questions[qCounter] = objReader.ReadLine();


    string test = question.Split('?')[qCounter];
    qCounter++;

    foreach (char part in test)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(part);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
} while (objReader.Peek() != -1 && qCounter < quest);
```

Comment: thanks dan it works